# Restart command not restarting console discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

When i run $restart in my discord server, it replies "restarting" but doesnt restart, it just prints $restart on my console (which is another script i have in my index.js to print commands) though the console doesnt close and re-open. it doesnt even close. Does this mean it has restarted or am i doing something wrong?
Here is my index.js for that part:

```
else if (command === '$restart') {
    return message.reply({
        embeds: [
            new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('GREEN')
            .setDescription('Restarting')
        ]
    })
    .then(()=>client.destroy()) // <<<<
    .then(()=>client.login('cooltokenhere')) // <<<<
}
})
client.login('cooltokenhere')
```

Comment: `client.destroy()` closes login and stops the code, so it won't restart. I'd recommend to use `pm2` for restarting your bot instead, so you need to run console command `pm2 restart index.js` and it will restart!

Comment: how would I put that into a code? @MegaMix_Craft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to use pm2 for restarting your bot, to use it you need to install it first using `npm i -g pm2`, and also you need to install `child_process` module using `npm i child_process`, after that you can restart your bot using this code:

```js
const child = require('child_process')

child.exec("pm2 restart index", (err, res) => {
if(err) return console.log(err)
})
```

But please note you have to start your bot using `pm2 start index.js` first!

Comment: If your bot runs under pm2, you can just simply use `process.exit()`. It will get started back by pm2. No need to exec anything.